# ionic3 ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND(file:///android_asset/www/index.html)

Tags: android, cordova, cordova-plugins, ionic3

There is a problem in understanding

I have the next:

**global packages:**

- @ionic/cli-utils : 1.1.2
- Cordova CLI      : 7.0.1
- Ionic CLI        : 3.1.2

**local packages:**

- @ionic/app-scripts              : 1.3.7
- @ionic/cli-plugin-cordova       : 1.2.0
- @ionic/cli-plugin-ionic-angular : 1.2.0
- Cordova Platforms               : android 6.2.3
- Ionic Framework                 : ionic-angular 3.2.1

**System:**

- Node       : v6.10.2
- OS         : OS X El Capitan
- Xcode      : not installed
- ios-deploy : not installed
- ios-sim    : not installed

Here are my steps:

`ionic start myApp tabs` 
`cd myApp` 
`cordova add platforme android` 
`cordova run android` 
**and I have the error:** 
 `ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND(file:///android_asset/www/index.html)` **in the emulator**

Everything worked well before I installed the plugin 
`$ ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-nativestorage`
end  `$ npm install --save @ionic-native/native-storage`

But I added 
 `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>` 
 into AndroidManifest.xml and it worked!!!

Why it worked without that line before?

Thanks all

Answer (score 4, accepted):

instead of `cordova run android` you need to use `ionic cordova run android`

Answer (score 0):

In my case this path is working:

var file = 'file:///android_asset/www/assets/lolc.html';